# Use a variable outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set `numbers` to be equal with `digits`.
How can I do that? I tried `'numbers' : digits` but it doesn't work.

```
// Checks if the checkbox is checked or not
$('#digits').change(
  function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      digits = true;
    } else {
      digits = false;
    }
});

// When the button "apply" is pressed it sets numbers equal to digits and calls the function test
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#apply').test({
        'numbers': digits // This is where I'm stuck
    });
});

(function($){
  var methods = {
    init : function( options, callbacks) {
      var settings = $.extend({
        'numbers': true,
    }, options);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    etc
    $.fn.test= function(method) {
      alert("SUCCESS");
      ...
      ...    
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[Working Example (JSFIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/u8HLB/17/)

Comment: Your `.test()` call happens just once, when the DOM is first loaded, and it will use the value of `digits` at that time. When the `.change()` handler runs, it won't have any effect on what was done earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialise your plugin you are giving it the value of `digits` at that stage. From the code you've posted, I'd guess that it is `undefined`. You need to update the value on the plugin each time it is changed via the checkbox.

A quick fix would be to move the code which initialises the plugin to the `change` handler of your checkbox, though you might also consider initialising the plugin once and implementing a setter method to allow you to update the value on the plugin after it has been initialised.

```
   // Checks if the checkbox is checked or not
    $('#digits').change(
      function(){

        $('#apply').test({
            'numbers': this.checked 
        });
    });
```

Comment: What if I have multiple checkboxes and more than one variable?

Comment: Can you try to make it clear in your question what you're actually trying to achieve? I've tried to do my best with the information you've given but, as it stands, it's all a bit abstract - at least to me.

Comment: I added a JSFIDDLE link showing what I'm trying to do. Each time I click apply I want my code to read if the checkboxes are checked or not.

Comment: Can you update the fiddle with a working version of the plug-in?

Comment: I updated the JSFIDDLE code. The example code I posted works as a password generator. What I want is when the user checks or unchecks one of the checkboxes to update the variables with `true` or `false` respectively.

Comment: The following fork of your fiddle does what you want. It could be done better, but it would involve refactoring the plugin code. http://jsfiddle.net/WFxVr/2/

Comment: This is better I think. Principle changes. 1. bind the plug-in to the element that outputs the password. 2. remove the click binding from the plug-in itself for more flexibility. 3. Initialise the plug-in once. 4. Call the generate password method from a click handler outside the plug-in. http://jsfiddle.net/9K4sa/1/

Comment: Thanks it works now! But for a reason it doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: There was an error on the selector for the checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/9K4sa/2/